# UIScollview and UIView alignment weird

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiview, uiscrollview

I have this piece of code:

```
scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 170, 320, 260)];
scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(960, 240);
[scrollView setPagingEnabled:YES];
scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;
scrollView.delegate = self;
[scrollView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];

[self.view addSubview:scrollView];


graphView = [[FDGraphView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 10, 320, 240)];
[graphView setLinesColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
[graphView setDataPointColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[graphView setDataPointStrokeColor:[UIColor grayColor]];
[graphView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];

[scrollView addSubview:graphView];
```

I expect to see this:

[image]

But instead I see this:

[image]

I get the expected on a new project using just a uiview and the above code, using a cocoa control FDGraphView (which is great by the way) I get the weird behaviour.

FDGraphView is a UIView subclass but uses UIScrollView also and works normally when added as a a subview of the viewController view,

any ideas??

**Edit: Apparently something in the code below is causing the problem**

```
- (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
    // resize your layers based on the view’s new bounds
    [[[self.view.layer sublayers] objectAtIndex:0] setFrame:self.view.bounds];
    if (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft) {
        [graphView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 150, 480, 150)];
        [graphView setNeedsDisplay];
        [refresh setFrame:CGRectMake(5, 305, 10, 10)];

        CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame];

        if (screenRect.size.height == 568)
        {
            //if iPhone 5+
            NSLog(@"iPhone 5+ Detected");
            [graphView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 150, 568, 150)];
            [graphView setNeedsDisplay];
        }


    }
    if (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait)
    {
        [graphView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 170, 320, 240)];
        [graphView setNeedsDisplay];
        [refresh setFrame:CGRectMake(5, 465, 10, 10)];
        CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame];

        if (screenRect.size.height == 568)
        {
            //if iPhone 5+
            NSLog(@"iPhone 5+ Detected");
            [graphView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 170, 320, 240)];
            [graphView setNeedsDisplay];
            [refresh setFrame:CGRectMake(5, 553, 10, 10)];

        }

    }
    if (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)
    {
        [graphView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 150, 480, 150)];
        [graphView setNeedsDisplay];
        [refresh setFrame:CGRectMake(5, 305, 10, 10)];

        CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame];

        if (screenRect.size.height == 568)
        {
            //if iPhone 5+
            NSLog(@"iPhone 5+ Detected");
            [graphView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 150, 568, 150)];
            [graphView setNeedsDisplay];
        }

    }
}


- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [self willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:[[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation] duration:0.5   ];

}
`
```

Comment: Are you using Autolayout or springs and struts which could be causing a difference between the two projects?

Comment: Unfortunately not, I even added the FDGraph class to a fresh project and it works normally as expected... really annoying - I wonder what is happening with it!

Comment: Ok Apparently something in above code is causing the problem!

Comment: Figured it out thanks for the help!

Comment: No problem.  Please consider deleting the question or posting your solution so your answer acceptance stays high.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this piece of code:

```
if (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait)
{
    [graphView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 170, 320, 240)];
    [graphView setNeedsDisplay];
    [refresh setFrame:CGRectMake(5, 465, 10, 10)];
    CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame];

    if (screenRect.size.height == 568)
    {
        //if iPhone 5+
        NSLog(@"iPhone 5+ Detected");
        [graphView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 170, 320, 240)];
        [graphView setNeedsDisplay];
        [refresh setFrame:CGRectMake(5, 553, 10, 10)];

    }

}
```

The lines of code:

```
    [graphView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 170, 320, 240)];
    [graphView setNeedsDisplay];
```

were getting called by a delegate moving the frame of my graphView! Stupid really...